# If $\log_{30}3=a,\log_{30}5=b$ then show what $\log_{30}8$ is

Tags: logarithms

If $\log_{30}3=a,\log_{30}5=b$ then show what $\log_{30}8$ is.

I am having trouble trying to get 8 to be some sequence with 5,30,3. Any hints?

Comment: Hint: $\log_{30} 2 = \log_{30} 30/15 = 1-(a+b)$

Comment: @GNUSupporter Yes, that is what I am trying to do! I don't see anything that can give 8 though.

Comment: $\log x^a = a \log x$

Comment: @GNUSupporter I am also aware of that.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Omg I see it

Comment: @GNUSupporter Thank you! The result is $3(1-a-b)$

Comment: @RiktasMath You can also answer your own question. ;)

Comment: Self-answering is [strongly encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 4):

$ \log_{30}8=\log_{30}2^3=3\log_{30}2=3\log_{30}\frac{30}{5\ast3}$

$3\log_{30}30-(3\log_{30}5+3\log_{30}3)=3-3b-3a=3(1-b-a)$